# How set selected default in Angular + 2

Tags: javascript, angular

Created an object with the value 'true' in 'dropOptions'. In HTML I called [selected] = "option.selected" to include the selection.

The intention is to include the selected = "selected" element in the object with the value 'true'.

Thanks for help!

```js
  dropOptions = [
    { name: "ID parceiro", value: 'partner', selected: true },
    { name: "ID", value: 'id' },
    { name: "Nome do Item", value: 'name' }
  ];
```

```html
          <select (change)="selectOption($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
            class="form-control gray-txt">
            <option [value]="option.value" [selected]="option.selected" *ngFor="let option of dropOptions">{{option.name}}</option>
          </select>
```

Comment: what do you mean by default?

Comment: set default value from dropdown option like this in component ```selectedOption = 'idB2W';```

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: The intention is to include the _selected = "selected"_ element in the object with the value 'true'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
      <select (change)="selectOption($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
        class="form-control gray-txt">
        <option [value]="option.value" [selected]="option.value === selectedOption" *ngFor="let option of dropOptions">{{option.name}}</option>
      </select>
```

Comment: I tried something similar, but it didn't work either.

Comment: What is the value of 'selectedOption'?

Comment: receive "id". Is a value from object.

Comment: Your suggestion helped. It was only necessary to include ng-model in the "option" tag. Tks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set default value other than `dropOptions array` like placeholder then do like this.

**component.html**

```
 <select (change)="selectOption($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption"
                class="form-control gray-txt">
                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                <option [value]="option.value" [selected]="option.selected" *ngFor="let option of dropOptions">{{option.name}}</option>
              </select>
```

**component.ts**

```
  selectedOption = 'Select';
```

And if you want set default from `dropOptions array` then try like this
**component.ts**

```
 selectedOption = 'idB2W';
```

this will set second item selected because we have set option value as `[value]="option.value"`.

Comment: tks for your help! It was necessary to change ng-model.